# Need help with texture bake and consolidating meshes for UNITY engine

Tags: mesh, texture-baking, unity

My friend is making a hobby game in Unity game engine and asked me to help with 3d models/animations.
I have zero experience except for this week of work and have made cups and clocks and hats etc (easy stuff).

I understand the modeling parts pretty ok, texturing somewhat ok, but baking not so ok.

Issues:

1. My friend wants NO SHADOWS OR LIGHTING (or just a single light) in my end products, but I don't know how to bake without the lights and get a clear texture bake.
   I found some sites, but the options in properties and in materials they had I don't have in my blender v2.75 and so I'm lost.
2. He griped or I should say unity engine griped at my end products because they are in too many parts. Even after I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>J</kbd> to add them together.  Unity says: too many mesh parts, it wants them all into 1.  So I'm very lost on this.

I Need help with:
Texture baking with out shadows and possible no lighting, but want clear textures.
How to consolidate/condense meshes into 1 file for unity.

Comment: please narrow down your question to only one question at a time. PS offering to pay for answers is definitely against the spirit of SE http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/133792/278094.

Comment: Well I dont know how to edit my post. nevermind found out how but my question is still 2 parts to one issue.

Comment: Are you using Cycles or Blender Internal?

Comment: cycles render  if thats what you mean

Comment: I have *never* seen Unity complain about too many parts, but I *have* seen it complain about too many vertices, which it handles smoothly and automatically by creating sub meshes, each about 65000 vertices.  In regards to the no lighting, perhaps a normal map, or probably running shadeless, and letting Unity handle the shading (which does not use Cycles or Blender shaders). EDIT: Oh, this got bumped up, I didn't realize this was a year old.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Bake Section in Properties Panel and choose "Diffuse Color", So that way your Baked Texture will not be affected by the lights and shadows.

[image]

[image]